# Javascript Libraries for Annotating Text?

Tags: javascript, open-source, text, annotations

I have googled and come up dry.

I am looking for a way to annotate text selections (with overlaps) and i was wondering if anyone knows of something like this available already?

My goal/use case is that a number of users will be presented the same blob of text and should all be able to independently annotate various selections of it.

thanks!

Answer (score 10):

This is, what I came up with a Google search:

- [Annotations jQuery plugin](http://snipplr.com/view/9250/annotations-jquery-plugin/)
- [ZURB JavaScript Annotation Plugin](http://www.zurb.com/playground/javascript-annotation-plugin)
- [jQuery Flot Annotate Plugin](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/annotating/index.html)

Maybe there's something you can use...

Comment: Thanks dave. I am still looking though :)

Comment: That third link is now dead.